DS18B20 having abnormal readings on STM32H7
I am using the DS18B20 temp sensor with the stm32h7 board and am just trying to get the correct temp and display it using putty, and I want to display a message saying Heat warning when the temp is above 45 degrees.
Here is my code so far:
#include "main.h"
#include "string.h"

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc2;
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc3;

FDCAN_HandleTypeDef hfdcan1;
FDCAN_HandleTypeDef hfdcan2;

I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c4;

LTDC_HandleTypeDef hltdc;

QSPI_HandleTypeDef hqspi;

RTC_HandleTypeDef hrtc;

SAI_HandleTypeDef hsai_BlockA2;
SAI_HandleTypeDef hsai_BlockB2;

MMC_HandleTypeDef hmmc1;

SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi2;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;

PCD_HandleTypeDef hpcd_USB_OTG_FS;

SDRAM_HandleTypeDef hsdram1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
#define     BUFSIZE 256
#define DS18B20_PORT GPIOA
#define DS18B20_PIN GPIO_PIN_1
uint8_t SendBuffer[BUFSIZE];
int Counter;
int KeyState=0;
int TouchX, TouchY;
uint8_t dataBuffer[10];

uint8_t VendorID, DeviceMode, Gesture, Status, Touchxh, Touchxl, Touchyh, Touchyl;
//uint8_t temp_lsb, temp_msb;
//int16_t temp_raw;
//float temperature;
uint8_t Temp_byte1, Temp_byte2;
uint16_t SUM, TEMP;

float Temperature = 0;
float Humidity = 0;
uint8_t Presence = 0;// Store temperature value

HAL_StatusTypeDef retval;
uint8_t Answer;
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void Display_Temp (float Temp);
void Set_Pin_Output (GPIO_TypeDef *GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin);
void Set_Pin_Input (GPIO_TypeDef *GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin);
uint8_t DS18B20_Start (void);
void DS18B20_Write (uint8_t data);
uint8_t DS18B20_Read (void);


void SystemClock_Config(void);
void PeriphCommonClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC2_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC3_Init(void);
static void MX_FDCAN1_Init(void);
static void MX_FDCAN2_Init(void);
static void MX_FMC_Init(void);
static void MX_LTDC_Init(void);
static void MX_QUADSPI_Init(void);
static void MX_RTC_Init(void);
static void MX_SAI2_Init(void);
static void MX_SDMMC1_MMC_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI2_Init(void);
static void MX_USART3_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C4_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  PeriphCommonClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_ADC2_Init();
  MX_ADC3_Init();
  MX_FDCAN1_Init();
  MX_FDCAN2_Init();
  MX_FMC_Init();
  MX_LTDC_Init();
  MX_QUADSPI_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  MX_SAI2_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init();
  MX_I2C4_Init();
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, 1);

  DS18B20_Init();

  while (1)
    {
       Presence = DS18B20_Start ();
       DS18B20_Write (0xCC);  // skip ROM
       DS18B20_Write (0x44);  // convert t

       Presence = DS18B20_Start ();
       DS18B20_Write (0xCC);  // skip ROM
       DS18B20_Write (0xBE);  // Read Scratch-pad

       Temp_byte1 = DS18B20_Read();
       Temp_byte2 = DS18B20_Read();
       printf("Raw Temp_byte1: %u, Temp_byte2: %u\n", Temp_byte1, Temp_byte2);
       TEMP = ((Temp_byte2<<8))|Temp_byte1;
       Temperature = (float)TEMP/16.0;  // resolution is 0.0625

       HAL_Delay(3000);
       Display_Temp(Temperature);
    }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
uint8_t DS18B20_Start (void)
{
    uint8_t Response = 0;
    Set_Pin_Output(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);   // set the pin as output
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin (DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN, 0);  // pull the pin low
    HAL_Delay(480);   // delay according to datasheet

    Set_Pin_Input(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);
        HAL_Delay(80);    // delay according to datasheet
    if (!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN))) Response = 1;    // if the pin is low i.e the presence pulse is detected
    else Response = -1;

    HAL_Delay (400); // 480 us delay totally.

    return Response;
}
void DS18B20_Write (uint8_t data)
{
    Set_Pin_Output(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);  // set as output

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if ((data & (1<<i))!=0)  // if the bit is high
        {
            // write 1
            Set_Pin_Output(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);  // set as output
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin (DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN, 0);  // pull the pin LOW
            HAL_Delay (1);  // wait for 1 us

            Set_Pin_Input(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);  // set as input
            HAL_Delay (50);  // wait for 60 us
        }

        else  // if the bit is low
        {
            // write 0
            Set_Pin_Output(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin (DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN, 0);  // pull the pin LOW
            HAL_Delay (50);  // wait for 60 us

            Set_Pin_Input(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);
        }
    }
}
uint8_t DS18B20_Read (void)
{
    uint8_t value=0;
    Set_Pin_Input (DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);

    for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        Set_Pin_Output(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);   // set as output
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, 0);  // pull the data pin LOW
        HAL_Delay (2);  // wait for 2 us
        Set_Pin_Input(DS18B20_PORT, DS18B20_PIN);  // set as input
        if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1))  // if the pin is HIGH
        {
            value |= 1<<i;  // read = 1
        }
        HAL_Delay (60);  // wait for 60 us
    }
    return value;
}

void Set_Pin_Output (GPIO_TypeDef *GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOx, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void Set_Pin_Input (GPIO_TypeDef *GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOx, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}
void Display_Temp (float Temp)
{
//    char str[20] = {0};
//    lcd_put_cur(0, 0);
//
//    sprintf (str, "TEMP:- %.2f ", Temp);
//    lcd_send_string(str);
//    lcd_send_data('C');
    // Display temperature and check for heat warning
              if (Temp > 40.0) {
                 snprintf(SendBuffer, BUFSIZE, "Heat Warning! Current Temperature: %.2f°C\n\r", Temp);
             } else {
                 snprintf(SendBuffer, BUFSIZE, "Current Temperature: %.2f°C\n\r", Temp);
             }
             HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, SendBuffer, strlen(SendBuffer), 100);
}
/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */


and the rest of the code is just generated code.
I have also tried to adjust the pin to be analog instead of output and input and these are some the readings I get:

Heat Warning! Current Temperature: 2272.25°C
Heat Warning! Current Temperature: 1055.44°C
Heat Warning! Current Temperature: 2231.31°C


You aren't putting any delay between writing consecutive '0' bits to the device.  You aren't putting any delay between the end of the read pulse, and actually sampling the bit you're trying to read.  You aren't putting any delay between the Convert T command and Read Scratchpad; I believe you have to wait something like 0.7 seconds there, for the conversion to actually finish.  It would be extremely helpful to look at the actual signal you are generating, on an oscilloscope or logic analyzer.

Well, those temperatures are definitely above 45 degrees, no matter which scale you're using. What is it you're measuring? The inside of a blast furnace?

Be aware that HAL_Delay() delays for milliseconds, not microseconds.

I'd recommend just configuring your pin as open-drain with a pull-up. Then when you want to configure it as an input, just set it high (and the pin will become high impedance). Otherwise you risk driving the pin while the DS18B20 also drives it, and frying something. Especially if you get the timing wrong, which you are probably doing.

I tried to check with the timing and still not sure if I got it right, but what I noticed is that when I set the pin A1 and A2 the exact same way, I get those abnormal reading when the sensor is connected to the A1 pin, but when I connect it to the A2 pin it isnt detected (I changed in code what pin to use)
Also added some prints for debugging and here is what I got, but still dont know what I am doing wrong
Temp_byte1: 247, Temp_byte2: 166
Raw TEMP: 42743, Calculated Temperature: 2671.44°C
